# In Windows 11, is there a way to change Sleep Mode to Shut Down after a certain period of time without activity?

Tags: sleep, shutdown, windows-11

I don't want my computer to be in sleep mode when I'm away from it for a long time, I want it to completely shut down. It is possible?

For example: today when I am away from the computer for more than 1 hour, it goes into Sleep Mode. But what I really want is for it to Shut Down after that 1 hour.

I saw that in the options of the power mode I use (High Performance) there is an option to set after how long from Sleep Mode the computer migrates to Hibernation, but it still doesn't solve the case.

Comment: Open a command prompt and enter  shutdown /s   .  The machine will turn off. It otherwise does not shut down after a period of inactivity.

Comment: Hi @John I didn't understand how this would solve my problem, does it change Sleep to Shut Down in the option setting in Power & Sleep?

Comment: I have not seen Windows inactivity timers shut down a machine. Windows 11 or prior. Suspend keeps apps open including unsaved files.  Shutdown will lose work trying to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I see @John , so it's impossible to make the computer shut down after a certain period of inactivity instead of just sleeping?

Comment: Yes, not possible to do.

Comment: Thanks for support @John

Comment: You can create a task to run shutdown.exe after a period of idling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows activity timers can suspend or hibernate a machine.

In this case files that are open remain open and work is saved.

If an activity timer shuts down a machine, unsaved work will be lost.

There is no native way that I know of to change the Sleep (or Hibernate) function to shut down instead - Windows 11 or prior Windows versions. That would cause numerous problems.